# Android media recorder not stop for the first time while recording

Tags: android, surfaceview, mediarecorder

I created a custom video recording in android using surface view. I did the code and its working in device(Sony xperia s,xperia z and Samsung grand). In Samsung galaxy s3,s4 and s5 devices,I didn't stop my video recording and it causes error in this line mediarecorder.stop() line.It will occur only for rear camera. For front camera it is working fine and if I came back to rear camera from front camera it is working. Kindly clarify this issue. I paste my code below.

```
CameraPreview class that extends SurfaceView:

    public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

        public static SurfaceHolder     mHolder;
        private       Camera            mCamera;
        private       List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
        private       Camera.Size       mPreviewSize;

        private static final String TAG = "CameraPreview";

        public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
            super(context);
            mCamera = camera;  
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {      
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {

            }
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {            
            try {
                this.getHolder().removeCallback(this);
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.release();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("Inside Main Exc",""+e);
            }   
        }

        private void stopPreviewAndFreeCamera() {    
            if (mCamera != null) {
                 mCamera.stopPreview();
                 mCamera.release();    
                 mCamera = null;
            }
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
            if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {                
                return;
            }

            try {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            } catch (Exception e) {               
            }

            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            try {
                Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                if (params.getSupportedFocusModes().contains(
                        Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {
                    params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                }

            List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
            Camera.Size size = sizes.get(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < sizes.size(); i++) {
                if (sizes.get(i).width > size.width)
                    size = sizes.get(i);
            }
            params.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);

            mCamera.setParameters(params);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("Exception value",""+e);
            }
        }
    }

Inside Main Class, I did the following:

 In onCreate(), I initialized the startcamera task:
 startCamera(currentCameraId);

 If I select Start button, then recordVideo() is called and Select Stop button, then recordCompleted() is called.

 private void startCamera(int cameraId) {
        try {
            mCamera = CameraAPI.getCameraInstance(this, cameraId);
            mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
            captureScreenFrame.addView(mCameraPreview);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

 private void recordVideo() {        
        if (isVideoRecording) {
                recordCompleted();
        } else {
            T = new Timer();
            T.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (tempCount == 31) {
                                recordCompleted();
                            } else {
                                recordValue.setText("00:" + tempCount);
                                tempCount++;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 1000, 1000);


            cameraFlip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cameraFlash.setVisibility(View.GONE);

           if (!prepareMediaRecorder()) {
                Toast.makeText(TrunqCameraActivity.this,
                        "Fail in prepareMediaRecorder()!\n - Ended -", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        mediaRecorder.start();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            });

            isVideoRecording = true;
        }
    }

 public void recordCompleted(){
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            T.cancel();                       
            MediaController mc = new MediaController(TrunqCameraActivity.this);           
            mc.setMediaPlayer(capturedVideoPreview);
            mc.setAnchorView(capturedVideoPreview);
            capturedVideoPreview.requestFocus();
            capturedVideoPreview.setMediaController(mc);
            capturedVideoPreview.setVideoPath(capturedFile.getPath());
            isVideoRecording = false;
    }

    private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {        
        String capturedFilePath = VIDEO_DIRECTORY.concat("TrunqVideo_" +
        new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()) + ".mp4");        
        capturedFile = new File(capturedFilePath);        
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mCamera.unlock();
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);   
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {            
            mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
            mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
        }

        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(capturedFilePath);
        mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(30000); 
        mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(50000000);  

        if (currentCameraId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
            mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
        } else {
            mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(270);
        }

        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();          
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {            
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {            
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }catch (Exception e){}
        return true;
    }
```